# Echoing values of check boxes, radio buttons and text box inputs

Tags: php, html

I am trying to write a PHP script that will calculate the total of how many checkboxes are checked, along with displaying a customer's name, card type and card number. This is done through a submit button. I am having problems writing the check box part of the script and I am not sure if I am doing it correctly or not. Does anyone have an easy solution for this type of problem?

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>  
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (isset($_POST['bulb1'])) {
    echo "Your total is $9.56"; }
if (isset($_POST['bulb2'])) {
    echo "Your total is $34.32"; }
if (isset($_POST['bulb3'])) {
    echo "Your total is $15.80"; }
if (isset($_POST['bulb4'])) {
    echo "Your total is $59.92"; }
$cName = $_POST['name'];
$cardType = $_POST['list'];
$cardNum = $_POST['number'];
echo $cName;
echo $cardType;
echo $cardNum;
$total_count = count($_POST['bulb']);
$total_amount = 0;
if(!empty($_POST['bulb'])){
  foreach($_POST['bulb'] as $bulb){ 
       $total_amount += $bulb;
 }
}


echo 'total amount is ' . $total_amount;

}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>  
    <title>Assignment 1: #4</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <header>
            <h1>CS310: Assignment 5: #2</h1><hr/>
        </header>
        <p>Please input your name in the box below!</p>
<form>  
    <input type="text" name="name"  size="40"/><hr>

    <h3>Four 100-watt light bulbs for $ 2.39</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="9.56" id="Lightbulb1"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 1!</label>
<h3>Eight 100-watt light bulbs for $ 4.29</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="34.32" id="Lightbulb2"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 2!</label>
<h3>Four 100-watt, long-life light bulbs for $ 3.95</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="15.80" id="Lightbulb3"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 3!</label>
<h3>Eight 100-watt, long-life light bulbs for $ 7.49</h3>
<input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="59.92" id="Lightbulb4"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 4!</label><hr>
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="V" id="Visa"/>Visa
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="M" id="MasterCard"/>MasterCard
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="A" id="American Express"/>American Express
    <input type="radio" name="list" value="D" id="Discover"/>Discover
    <hr><br>
    Enter your credit card number here:<input type="text" name="number" id="creditCardNumber" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <br>
   </form>
    <hr><br>&copy; Created by: Jamie McGraw, 6/16/15,
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pass all the checkboxes as an array of single variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can make some changes in your html

```
<h3>Four 100-watt light bulbs for $ 2.39</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="9.56" id="Lightbulb1"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 1!</label>
<h3>Eight 100-watt light bulbs for $ 4.29</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="34.32" id="Lightbulb2"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 2!</label>
<h3>Four 100-watt, long-life light bulbs for $ 3.95</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="15.80" id="Lightbulb3"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 3!</label>
<h3>Eight 100-watt, long-life light bulbs for $ 7.49</h3>
    <input type="checkbox" name="bulb[]" value="59.92" id="Lightbulb4"/><label for="Lightbulb1">Check box for Lightbulb Option Number 4!</label><hr>
```

> create your input checkbox to array as bulb[]

Now in your php script

```
 // for counting total no of checkbox checked
 $total_count = count($_POST['bulb']);
 // for total amount initialize it with zero
 $total_amount = 0;
 if(!empty($_POST['bulb'])){
      foreach($_POST['bulb'] as $bulb){ 
           $total_amount += $bulb;
         // getting total amount by adding it to every new value
     }
 }


  echo 'total amount  = ' . $total_amount;
   echo "<br>";
   echo 'Card Type  = ' . $_POST["list"];
  echo "<br>";
  echo 'Card Number  = ' . $_POST["number"];
```

Comment: for some reason I am not able to display a result from this code edit. Any reason in particular? I also need to be able to echo the name, card type and card number of the customer.

Comment: Your form tag is empty.. you need to specify **method** and **action** in your form tag

Comment: Made changes to the answer. it might be helpful. also add **method="POST"** in your form

Comment: That's what it was! Thank you, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

Need to specify the **method in the form either "post or get"** and  for you it is **"post method"**

Use form like

```
<form name="item" method="post">
```